# Folders in S3 Bucket not visible in Web Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

After deleting a few folders in our S3 bucket, I am not able to see any of my folders through the web console. We had around 10 folders and ended up deleting 6 of them. The remaining four show up when I do an 'ls' on that S3 bucket through the CLI but the bucket shows up empty on the web console. 
When I turn on 'Versions' I see everything (including the 6 folders that were deleted). Am I overlooking something extremely simple?

Comment: How long has this been going on? If it's still coming through the CLI, it sounds like a problem on the web console. Log out, go get a long cup of coffee and try again?

Comment: It's been happening since last Thursday (07/19/2018). When I first started deleting the folders one at a time, it would take a few hours for the web console to update the info. After the last delete (which was the biggest folder) the CLI info updated within an hour or so but the web console just shows up empty.

Comment: Yeah - if it's been going on that long, but you are still getting positive results in the CLI still sounds like a web console problem. You are probably better off contacting AWS support than getting support from SO.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks for contributing :D

Answer (score 1):

Folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3.

For example, you could create an object like this:

```
aws s3 cp foo.txt s3://my-bucket/folder1/folder2/foo.txt
```

This would instantly 'create' `folder1` and `folder2`. Or, to be more accurate, the folders would 'appear' but they don't actually exist because the full filename (Key) of the object is `folder1/folder2/foo.txt`.

If you were then to delete that object, the folders would 'disappear' because they never actually existed.

Sometimes, if a system wants to forcefully make a folder 'appear', it can create a zero-length object with the same name as the folder. This makes the folder 'appear', but it is really the empty file that is appearing.

**Bottom line:** Don't worry about creating and deleting folders. They will appear when necessary and disappear when not being used. Do not try to map normal filesystem behaviour to Amazon S3.